# Jhipster generated Springboot code fails to starup secondtime with hikari error SQLSTATE(08003)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jhipster, hikaricp, dbconnection

Jhipster version 7.8.1
Springboot version 2.6.6
PostgreSQL 14.9
OS : Ubuntu

I generated a spring boot project and connected it to PostgreSQL successfully very first time.

The second time the application startup threw the below error.

```
    2023-11-28 22:48:56.595 ERROR 18292 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.app.domain.Student]

2023-11-28 22:48:56.606  WARN 18292 --- [ daseapp-task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : Hikari - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@707a307 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:883)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getMetaData(PgConnection.java:1315)
```

I tried to stop the application through Ctl+C and also tried the actuator/shutdown. Always the Hikari error shows for subsequent bootup.

When I recreated the Database and restarted the db server, the spring boot application was able to connect for the first time successfully. Again second time the same Hikari error.

Below is the spring yaml configuration

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/XXXX
    username: XXXX
    password: XXXX
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
      connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
      testWhileIdle: true
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 60000
      idleTimeout : 600000
      validationTimeout : 300000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      maxLifetime : 1800000      
    removeAbandoned : true
    removeAbandonedTimeout : 60
```

Comment: Are you using your own PostgreSQL instance or the one that ships with JHipster (runs via Docker Compose)?

Comment: I tried docker-compose provided by jhipster. Now tested with my own instance. Both have the same issue.

Comment: Are you able to share the output of `jhipster info` so I can re-create your project and see if I can reproduce? Also, what OS are you using?